# How to include optional relations in C# using Code First Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, include, code-first

Having the DB below I would like to retrieve all bricks in C# and include the Workshops on those BrickBacks that has any.

I managed to retrieve all the Bricks and include the BrickBacks by simply doing

```
context.Bricks.Include(b=>b.Back).ToList()
```

But in this case BrickBack is an abstract class which its subclass ***may*** contain a Workshop but this is not always the case.

Unfortunately I can't just do

```
context.Bricks.Include(b=>b.Back).Include(b=>b.Back.Workshop).ToList()
```

How can this be done?

[image: DB Diagram]

Comment: Does this work ? : context.Bricks.Include(b=>b.Back.Workshop).ToList()

Answer (score 0):

This could work `context.Bricks.Include("Back").Include("Workshop").ToList()`

`WorkShop` will be null if `Workshop_Id` is null in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Maybe you can approach it from a different angle:

```
ConcreteBacks.Include(b => b.WorkShop)
             .Include(b => b.Bricks)
             .AsEnumerable()
             .SelectMany(b => b.Bricks)
```

This will pull all `ConcreteBacks` and the included data from the database and then return the `Bricks` in a flattened list.

The `AsEnumerable()` is necessary because EF only includes data off the root entities in the result set. Without `AsEnumerable()` this would be `Brick` and the `ConcreteBacks` would be ignored. But now EF only knows about the part before `AsEnumerable()`, so it includes everything off `ConcreteBack`.